If $(1-x)f(y)=xg(z)$, $f$ is increasing in $y$ and $g$ is decreasing in $z$ what can we say about the nature of solution?
I have the equation $(1-x)f(y)=xg(z)$, where $x,y,z\in (0, 1)$. We have two solutions $(x,y,z)$ and $(x^*, y^*, z^*)$, where $x\leq x^*$ and $z\leq z^*$. Is it true that $y\leq y^*$?
Suppose $y>y^*$, then $(1-x)f(y)>(1-x^*)f(y^*)$, implies that $xg(z)>x^*g(z^*)$. So I only have $g(z)>g(z^*)$. According to hypothesis it is trivially true, so I cannot find a contradiction. Or it has to be true? Am I missing something? Can anyone give any hints? Thank you!

Not true. For a counter-example take $f(t)=t, g(t)=1-t$ and look at the solutions $(\frac 1 2, \frac 3  4, \frac  1 4)$ and $(\frac 1  2, \frac 1  2, \frac 1 2 )$.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Why is a counterexample no answer?

@RedFive You make no sense whatsoever. Please read the question and the answer again.
